# Laravel 9 Composer detected issues with PHP Version

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, composer-php, ubuntu-18.04

I saw other have asked the question, but non of the solutions seem to be working for me and maybe others

##### Specs

- PHP 7.4 for Laravel 8
- PHP 8.2 for Laravel 9
- Ubuntu Server 18.4
- Nginx version 1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- Composer 2.5.4

##### My `composer.json` file

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "ext-imagick": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "defuse/php-encryption": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/helpers": "*",
        "laravel/installer": "^4.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "nategood/httpful": "^0.2.20",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

The upgrade from 8 to 9 is no problem, but on my website, I get the following error:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".

In the end, I want that my project runs on Laravel 9 with PHP 8.2

##### What I had tried

Add in `composer.json`

```json
{
    "config": {
        "platform-check": false
    }
}
```

Or

```json
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.4.33"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to switch PHP versions with `sudo update-alternatives --config php`.

I also changed the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/YOURSITENAME` file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

fastcgi_cache_path /var/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:10m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    server_tokens off;
    listen 443 ssl  http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl  http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/CENSORED/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot 
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/CENSORED/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/CENSORED/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot 

    server_name CENSORED;

    root /var/www/kfz/public/;
    index index.php;

    error_page 403 404 /404.html;

    location = /404.html {
        internal; #return 404
    }

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
        return 404;
    
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
        try_files $uri =404;

        # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
        # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 30s;
    }
}
```

I only changed the line `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;`
from `php7.4-fqm.sock` to `php8.2-fpm.sock`.

That all solutions did not work for me, so I checked the PHP version in composers usage with: `composer -vvv about 2>&1 | grep "PHP"`.

Output:

> Running 2.5.4 (2023-02-15 13:10:06) with PHP 8.2.3 on Linux / 4.15.0-206-generic
>
> Composer - Dependency Manager for PHP - version 2.5.4

Then I decided to delete PHP 7.4 with the following command: `sudo apt-get purge 'php7.4*'`.

Then the error:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".

Was gone, but then I had the `500 SERVER ERROR`.

So for me a solution for the Error was to delete the old PHP version no matter what PHP version the composer has.

So make sure you have no older PHP version then 8.1 installed or enabled.

I will post a solution for the error 500 as soon as I find one. Or maybe someone has an idea.

Comment: Please don't check for the PHP version your webserver uses on the CLI. Check this through `phpinfo()` in a webserver request. The shell might use a completely different version of PHP than your webserver

Comment: "Was gone, but then I had the 500 SERVER ERROR." - check your webserver's log files for more details. Without seing the root cause for that error, it's impossible to tell you how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem Solved.

in `/var/log/nginx` are the logs from nginx. There were no issues.

But in my Laravel project `/storage/app/logs` was an log with the following error:

> Undefined constant Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL

Quick search and it is an **Trusted Proxies error**.

so here all my changes:

in `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php` update `use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware` to `use Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies as Middleware`.

Next I updated the `$headers` property definition:

from

```
//before
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
```

to

```
//after
protected $headers =
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO |
    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

then you have to remove the `fideloper/proxy` Composer dependency from your application with:

```
composer remove fideloper/proxy
```

and it worked perfectly!

could be also read in the Laravel upgrade 8 to 9 doc.

link to the doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade?ref=hackernoon.com

I hope i could help others with that.

Comment: Great to read you solved it +1!. For your comment that it could be read in the docs: Why not add a link to where you found that? That's often a good addition to an answer. Cheers & Welcome to SO!